# Way to handle rapidly changing current demands and excess heat

Tags: power-supply, inductor, switching, thermal

So I have a circuit like this:
[image: Circuit]

And I am driving it with a desktop power supply at 5A (<1 Volts varies by coil). The issue that I am having is that my power supply is overheating. I am rapidly switching the control signals, the timing is such that there is a brief period where both switches are open. I need the circuit to operate in this way, however; my belief is that due to the fact that the power supply's draw briefly dips to 0 during this timeframe somehow this is generating excess heat in the supply. This is supported by the fact that as I increase the frequency of the control signal switching the time to overheating gets shorter. The power supply can also indefinitely sit at full power.

My initial idea is to add something in the circuit so that the power supply can continue to supply current during this switching period but I am unsure how to do that or whether it would actually be the best approach. Does anyone have any ideas how to approach this? Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps add some cooling?

Comment: @SolarMike It's a desktop power supply so it isn't really possible to add cooling. At least not easily.

Comment: It is always possible to add or improve cooling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all an idea of 'rapidly' would be useful. Are these MOSFET or mechanical relays? At least an idea of the actual impedance of the coils is needed to solve the issue.

Anyway, I had the *exact same* issue driving something like fuel injectors. When you supply a demagnetized coil there is a relatively slow inrush (coil are actually used to control current inrush!) until the core saturates, then the coil turn substantially into a resistor (the winding) and draw in lots of current. Of course it depends on your coil design but the basic idea is that.

Now, it really depends on what your coil is doing with the power you apply. However with coil used as solenoid actuators often you only need a fraction of the power to hold position after it has completed the movement. Real life example: a gas injector at 12V has 1 ohm resistance and something like 4mH of impedance. That would be 12A of current; however it only needs them only for the opening motion (about 2ms), after that you only need to give it 4A to keep open (for maybe 20ms, in this example).

If this situation applies to you then you might look for a peak-hold drive (it's quite common for solenoid). They also call it relay coil power saver. In fact they make ICs specifically for that, if you are already using a MOSFET you only need to add the controller.

Thing number two: independantly of your driving needs it's possible that the wiring inductance from the power supply is giving issues. In my case with a peak of 12A and a 5A supply there was also the need to supply the opening current. The idea is quite simple: put a *huge* capacitor in your circuit. You can estimate the Joules needed for magnetizing your coil from the current and the inductance. Then size your capacitor for these joules at your working voltage (with some extra for leakage and luck). When you trigger you coil the capacitor is almost dumped but the supply won't suffer. By the way I had to use 33mF (yes 33000µF) but it works fine :D

Comment: So by rapidly I mean that the control signals are switching at approximately 500Hz. Unfortunately while the coil is powered the required power stays constant in my use case. I'm going to look into a capacitor that seems like it might be helpful here.

Comment: Well, only solenoid are useful on peak hold. However 500 Hz could be a nasty frequency to impose to the power supply depending on how handle transient. Try the capacitor (be careful with the charging surge)